# Mimicking Console and Output Matlab/Rstudio-Style Environment in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, interface

I am trying to crudely approximate the RStudio or Matlab Workspace environment in Mathematica by having a specific notebook function as the "console notebook" where I execute commands and another notebook function as the "output notebook".

Is there a simple way to only output the evaluated code from the specific notebook I designate as the "console notebook" to the notebook I designate as the "output notebook"?

Unfortunately, the code below outputs from any open notebook to the output notebook ("outputNB" below).  I would just like to output from consoleNB to outputNB. Btw, code is taken from [wolfram community forum](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/187776)

```
outputNB=NotebookCreate[];

$DisplayFunction=(NotebookWrite[outputNB,{Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@#,"Output"]},After]
)&;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could check in your `$DisplayFunction` if your `EvaluationNotebook` matches your console notebook. Or add some option (`CellEvaluationFunction`?) to your notebook that wraps your code into a `Block` that changes the `$DisplayFunction`